# Onboarding Email First Contact after Job Application

Tags: applications, onboarding

I applied to a job a couple weeks ago and had not heard anything from the company until two days ago when I received an onboarding email with a link and a PIN asking me to click the link and enter my first and last name and the PIN.

As far as I can tell, it is a real company. When I google the company, it comes up with a stock price, and the first link is the same website that the email address behind the onboarding email was from. On Glassdoor, it says it's a company of 1000-5000 with 30 reviews, 88 jobs, and a few other items listed.

I tried the link on safeweb.norton.com and on scanurl.net and both showed that it was safe, but I don't know how reliable these sites are.

What should my next steps be in this situation? As far as I can tell, the email is legitimate, but I have never heard of a company initiating contact with an onboarding email. I have thought about contacting the company through their website or just going through with the email. I don't believe there is anything malicious that they could do with just my name and a PIN that they provided.

Comment: Say more about the application process.  Are you sure you really applied to the company you think you did?

Comment: Why don't you just log in with your name and pin and see what you get? You shouldn't disclose confidential information until you are sure it's legit, but name and pin are not confidential. It might be a portal with further instructions and information.

Comment: This  depends highly on what you mean by "onboarding email".   Are you  sure it's not a  sign-up page for some kind of online testing system to  do a preliminary skill test?

Comment: I just applied through Indeed. It's possible that the Indeed profile is fake, but the email address seems to be from the actual companies website. I suppose it is possible that the entire website is fake, but it seems fairly well fleshed out. All of the links work and there is quite a bit of information on it.

Comment: I tried calling the company and asking about it. After I read them the email address, the person on the other end asked for me to give them a few minutes, and then they hung up. I think I'll try calling again later and if that still doesn't work, I will message them through their website.

Comment: @Ertai87 I went ahead and followed the link and filled out my name and the PIN, and definitely appears to be what they send to people that have been hired. It's asking me to fill out a W-4 and an I-9 form and give them direct deposit authorization. Obviously, I'm not gonna do that without having any other contact with the company.

Comment: @Gary17 "I tried calling the company and asking about it. After I read them the email address, the person on the other end asked for me to give them a few minutes, and then they hung up." <-  calls get disconnected sometimes, or they hit the hang up button by accident sometimes.  It doesn't happen twice though.  If they don't answer the question when you call them again, it's probably a scam; you should get rid of it and maybe report to the local authorities for followup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest calling them and asking.  They have a website.  That website ought to have a phone number.  This behavior is odd enough that asking about it would not be unreasonable, and whatever their reaction is, it's bound to provide further clarity.  Be uncertain, possibly concerned, and respectful.

More to the point, if it is some sort of scam, the email they've sent you and the link associated with it are poisoned.  The website you find from searching the company name and the phone number associated with it are far less likely to be.

There is a good chance that their system has been compromised in some way.  If that's true... well, contacting them like this with your concerns would potentially be doing them a favor, and would reflect well on you as a potential employee... but *do* be respectful.  Being obnoxious about it will quickly destroy any credit you might manage to build up by other means.

Answer (score 0):

> I have never heard of a company initiating contact with an onboarding
> email.

They didn't initiate the contact. You did when you applied for the job. Find their contact information on their website, ask to speak to someone in HR, and ask them if the email is legitimate.